# AWS RDS SQLServer DENY view any database

Tags: sql-server, amazon-web-services

We've created a dedicated login for application with special grants (only select, insert, update, delete).
Now we would like to deny to show the list of the other databases for the limited user.

These are our operations:

```sql
CREATE LOGIN test_user WITH PASSWORD = 'test_pwd', DEFAULT_DATABASE = TEST_DB;
GO
USE TEST_DB
CREATE USER test_user FROM LOGIN test_user;
GO
EXEC sp_addrolemember 'db_datareader', 'test_user';
EXEC sp_addrolemember 'db_datawriter', 'test_user';
```

When we try to do:

```sql
DENY VIEW ANY DATABASE TO test_user;
```

The result is: **Msg 4613, Level 16, State 1, Line 1. Grantor does not have GRANT permission.**

How can we deny the user to show the other databases ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Who are you running the command as? sounds like they don't have the permission to grant or deny privileges

Comment: I'm using the sa user of sqlserver. 
Note that is an instance of AWS RDS that might can have particular permissions or limitations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**I asked to AWS Developer Support Plan and the response is:**

Reviewing your case, I understand that you would like to restrict certain users to view the list of databases in the RDS SQL instance. The T-SQL commands you referred to achieve the same is right and would work perfectly outside RDS. Since Amazon RDS is a managed service, it does not provide shell access to DB instances, and it restricts access to certain system procedures and tables that require advanced privileges.

By default the master user is granted with only the following system privileges [1]

```
ALTER ANY CONNECTION, ALTER ANY LINKED SERVER, ALTER ANY LOGIN, ALTER SERVER STATE, ALTER TRACE, CONNECT SQL, CREATE ANY DATABASE, VIEW ANY DATABASE, VIEW ANY DEFINITION, VIEW SERVER STATE, ALTER ANY SERVER ROLE, ALTER ANY USER
```

Also, the following server-level roles are not currently available in Amazon RDS [2]

```
bulkadmin
dbcreator
diskadmin
securityadmin
serveradmin
sysadmin
```

As master user has only permission to View Any Database and have no privilege to GRANT itself 'dbcreator' role, it can't GRANT or DENY View any Database for any users. That is why you are getting this error: 'Grantor does not have GRANT permission'.

References:

1. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/UsingWithRDS.MasterAccounts.html
2. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/CHAP_SQLServer.html#SQLServer.Concepts.General.FeatureSupport.UnsupportedRoles